# different between empty variable and initialized variable

Tags: javascript, callback

I am thinking my question is wrong or not meaningful like that I am getting better way to ask well coming to point...

I am learning callback functions in javascript

```
const posts = [
    {title: 'A', body: 'This is Body Of A'},
    {title: 'B', body: 'This is Body Of B'},
    {title: 'C', body: 'This is Body Of C'},
]
```

and I am creating those posts:-

```
function createPosts(post){
    setTimeout(function(){
        posts.push(post);
    },2000);
}
```

getting them and displaying on html:

```
function getPosts(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        let output = ''
        posts.forEach(function(post){
            output += `<li>${post.title}</li>`
        });
        document.body.innerHTML = output;
    }, 1000);
}
```

in get posts i am setting to empty it was listing all post titles,
if i am initializing output it was listing only one.

```
function getPosts(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        let output;
        posts.forEach(function(post){
            output = `<li>${post.title}</li>`
        });
        document.body.innerHTML = output;
    }, 1000);
}
```

so What is the difference between making an empty variable and initializing variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the string concatenation `+=`: see section `String operators` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

The following line will append the new `li` item to the `output`

```
output += `<li>${post.title}</li>`
```

In the other example you use the assign operator `=`:
This will assign the `li` element to `output` - whatever was stored in `output` before is lost:

```
output = `<li>${post.title}</li>`
```

Answer (score 0):

As you intended the value future values are Strings so it's always better to use empty string as initial value, in your code than you need not to check before applying any of [string related method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) otherwise you need to add a check every time you use string method on variable

```js
let str = ''

console.log(str.replace(/.*/g , 'Hello'))

let noStr;

console.log(noStr.replace(/.*/g , 'Hello'))
```